# parser.getTokens() gives out junk data and singlecharacters PDFBox-1.8.9 version

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I am new to pdfbox. I am using `pdfbox-app-2.0.0-RC1` version to fetch the entire text from the pdf using PDFTextStripperByArea. Is it possible for me to get each string separately?

For Example, 
In the following text,

> Nomination : Name&Address
>   Shipper : shipper name

I need Nomination as seperate string and "Name&Address" as separate string. Instead I am getting each character separately. I have tried with different Pdfs. For most pdfs I am able to get the exact string but for few pdfs I don't.

I am using the following code to get the separate string.

```
for (PDPage page : doc.getPages()) {
    PDFStreamParser parser = new PDFStreamParser(page);
    parser.parse();
    List<Object> tokens = parser.getTokens();
       for (int j = 0; j < tokens.size(); j++) {
                Object next = tokens.get(j);
                if (next instanceof Operator) {
                    Operator op = (Operator) next;
                    if (op.getName().equals("Tj")) {
                        COSString previous = (COSString) tokens.get(j - 1);
                        String string = previous.getString();
                        System.out.println("string1===" + string);
                        if (string.contains("Plant")) {
                            int size = al.size();
                            al.add(string);
                            stop = false;
                            continue;
                        }
                        if (!string.contains("_") && !stop) {
                            if (string.contains("Nomination")) {
                                stop = true;
                            } else {
                                al.add(string);
                            }
                        }

                    } else if (op.getName().equals("TJ")) {
                        COSArray previous = (COSArray) tokens.get(j - 1);
                        for (int k = 0; k < previous.size(); k++) {
                            Object arrElement = previous.getObject(k);
                            if (arrElement instanceof COSString) {
                                COSString cosString = (COSString)arrElement;
                                String string = cosString.getString();
                                System.out.println("string2====>>"+string);
                                al.add(string);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

I am getting the following output:

> string2====>>Nom
>
> string2====>>i
>
> string2====>>na
>
> string2====>>t
>
> string2====>>i
>
> string2====>>on
>
> string1===
>
> string2====>>(
>
> string2====>>T
>
> string2====>>o
>
> string1===
>
> string2====>>Loa
>
> string2====>>di
>
> string2====>>ng
>
> string1===
>
> string2====>>Fa
>
> string2====>>c
>
> string2====>>i
>
> string2====>>l
>
> string2====>>i
>
> string2====>>t
>
> string2====>>y
>
> string2====>>)

Comment: *I am getting each character separately* - no, there are some multi-letter groups among the outputs you posted. That been said, the reason why you do not get the whole string but instead these pieces, is that in the pdf not your whole string is drawn at once but as these pieces. If you want the whole string, you have to put the pieces together, and that is what the text stripper does for you.

Comment: Current version is RC2. (Although this won't change anything about the "problem" you are having, things are exactly as described by mkl).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So, the pdfbox parses the pdf based on how it was written.???

Comment: getting junk data in another pdf while using getTokens() --

string1====>> !"##$#
string1====>>
string1====>%&'
string1====>>()
string1====>>
string1====>>
string1====>>"$*
string1====>>*!$*
string1====>>
string1====>>"$*
string1====>>*! +
string1====>>
string1====>>,
string1====>>-,.)
string1====>>
string1====>>
string1====>>$#/0*1"
string=== 
string===
string1====>>%23.4
string1====>>$1"$ #1
string1====>>.)
string1====>>,5
string1====>>4.)2,4
string1====>>6)))

Whereas while using pdfStripper1.getText(pdDoc); method returns the proper text. Is there any problem with the parser funciton??